# Tensorflow Lite gives me 0% accuracy for any image

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Here is my [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VulwTqKEAnQJs8HSEDlNpPfDc-sRLX-P?usp=sharing) which anyone should be able to run in 5 seconds. The predictions are always 0. I suspect the problem is in these two lines. Or perhaps my tflite model is corrupt or wrong?

```
label_id, prob = classify_image(interpreter, np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)/255 )
#label_id, prob = classify_image(interpreter, img )
```

Answer (score 1):

Think I figured it out. Basically the output from the classify_image() function needs furthur processing to be useable. So I need to do this on the output:

```
label_index= np.argmax(probs_lite)
score = tf.nn.softmax(probs_lite)

print(
  "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
  .format(class_names[label_index], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```

And here's my full script in case anyone has similiar issue in the future:

```
import itertools, time, os, numpy  as np,sys
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

def lite_model(images):
  interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  interpreter.set_tensor(interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index'], images)
  interpreter.invoke()
  return interpreter.get_tensor(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index'])

class_names = ['empty_court', 'occupied_court' ]

path_to_tflite = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    "court.tflite",
    "https://mysite.site/AI/court.tflite",
    untar=False)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter( path_to_tflite )
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
_, height, width, _ = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['shape']
print("Image Shape (", width, ",", height, ")")

image_url = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Court', origin='https://mysite.site/share/court4.jpg' )
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_url, target_size=( width, height ) )
os.remove(image_url) # Remove the cached file

img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
probs_lite = lite_model( np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)/255 )[0]
print ( probs_lite )

label_index= np.argmax(probs_lite)
score = tf.nn.softmax(probs_lite)

print(
  "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
  .format(class_names[label_index], 100 * np.max(score))
)
```